# Impact of combining projects in the build path on servlets

Tags: java, eclipse, multiple-projects

I am writing an application in Eclipse, that has a servlet, and an android component. There are common classes to both so, being a bit of noob, I have moved the common classes into a new project to centralise the common code.

I then reference the common classes in my servlet and the android project by including the "common class" project in the build path for each. I do not get any compile errors as a result of using the, now centralised, common classes.

My concern is the impact on the servlet. When deploying the jar for the servlet, I merely export all my .class files and push it onto the server. Will the common classes project be automatically included now that I have included an additional project as well ?

If you have better ideas or best practice architecting common classes/multi-project builds, I am also interested to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up your common code project as a dependancy in the build path of the servlet project then you can use ant build scripts to grab everything you need.

[here is the ant help page for eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-81_basics.htm)

When referencing your common code project for your Android application, be sure to Identify your common project as an android library (right click on project -> Properties -> Android (on the left) -> check the check box that says this is an Android library) and then be sure to set the Android library reference in your Android application project (right click on project -> Properties -> Android (on the left) -> click "Add" in the Libraries box and select your common code project).

[here is more about android projects and library projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html)